# Force Save Sitefinity Widget MVC Controller Property

Tags: c#, widget, sitefinity

I am making a Sitefinity Widget using an MVC Controller. The widget shows and all that, no problem there. What I would like to do is save data for the widget in JSON form in a hidden property. I know how to make the property hidden via an attribute but I want to know how to POST data to my controller and set a property on the controller which will be saved in sf_control_properties table. Normally controller properties only get saved here when editing a widget's properties and clicking save in Admin UI. My control will have two modes (User view and Admin view). I am not making a custom designer via the edit modal popup. I am showing the design view while in page design mode on the widget itself. I have a save button that will do a POST to the controller on the backend. I want it so set a property and then persist it to the sf_control_properties table like a normal edit->modal->Save would do. I know I could connect directly to SQL and write the value but is there a better way to force a Widget Property to save in an MVC Controller than SQL brute force? Here is an example of my controller setup.

```
[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "MyWidget", Title = "My Widget", SectionName = "Dashboard")]
public class MyWidgetController : Controller
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    public string CustomData {get;set;} //JSON string data

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var viewModel = this.CustomData.FromJson<MyWidgetViewModel>();
       return View(ViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(MyWidgetModel model)
    {
        this.CustomData = model.ToJson();
    }
}
```

So basically when I do an ajax post to this controller I want to set this.CustomData = postModel.ToJson() and persist it to the sf_control_properties table.

I am doing this to avoid making a custom Dynamic Module with my own table, etc. When control loads in normal user view I will convert the this.CustomData property to C# class and use it in my razor view....

Comment: When you are in Design mode of the page, edit the widget set something to the customData property and Save the widget - you can observe what service is being called in this case that is saving the value to the sf_control_properties table and maybe try to use the same service yourself.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing on the way home. But would prefer if there was better way than manually calling a REST call.

Comment: I see that its the PUT command of ControlPropertyService.svc. I just wish there was a class in c# for Sitefinity that would do this for me or something. I don't want to call a service like this....

Comment: Then, like you said, it might be better to store this data in a dynamic module (or list, or content block, etc.)

Comment: Even storing the data in a custom configuration field is a better idea than in control properties